# How can I make a command that puts an output when an entity count is above a certain number?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-redstone

I need an execute command that outputs as 'true' when the number of Iron Ingots on the ground is above 100. I have attempted this in the only two ways I could think of, and so far neither have been successful.

The first thing I tried was to make a comparator output from the Command Block with `/execute if @e [nbt...`. That only outputs a signal strength of 1, no matter how many Iron Ingots there were.
The other way I tried was to use a limit, but that would only work if I needed it to put an output if it was less than 100.

[edit] OK so somebody marked this question as a duplicate of how to count items on the ground, so I have to explain why its not apparently. So the other one specifically asked about bed-wars. This one could be applied to bed wars I guess, but the other one didn't answer my question. (well somebody might have I was just too dumb to understand it.) So I redid the question into this one, which again is just for my knowledge about command blocks, so if I need something like this in the future. Sorry if my edit was a little wordy, I have never been good at English anyway.

Comment: I voted to close this question as a duplicate. The only missing thing for you is then to do `/execute if score <selector> <scoreboard> matches 100.. run <command>`

Comment: If the question is different, and additional information is needed in the answer, they should not be considered duplicate. Rather, your comment should be an answer and the two questions can be linked.

Answer (score 0):

try using the test for command. I learned that when you use "filters" as I call them, it can count the number of entities that match those requirements, for example, if I use /testfor @e[name=steve,type=zombie] it will count each zombie that has the name steve, so let say I have five zombies but two have the name steve the signal strength of the redstone will only be two

Comment: Didn't they get rid of the test for command in 1.13?

Comment: Update guys: So what I tried next was to use limit on an unless command. IT DIDN'T WORK! sigh. the code I tried was this: /execute unless entity @e[type=minecraft:item,limit=1,distance=..3] I thought that putting a limit would make the command block not activate until it had reached the limit. That would be perfect for me because I don't want to have an output until the limit of 100 had been reached. To @FabianRöling I don't know how to do all that score stuff, if you could point me to a YouTube video that would be helpful. (how do you make the score the same as the number of iron ingots?)

Comment: Anyone? please help...